# CM 10.2 Won't Boot (Black Screen) After Adb Sync System

Tags: android, adb, cyanogenmod

I've successfully built CM 10.2 and installed it onto my Galaxy S4. I wanted to start experimenting with the source by tracing API calls through the different layers of Android system - I added a log statement to the SensorManager.java's getDefaultSensor method:

```
Log.i("Tracing","SensorManager.java getDefaultSensor(...)");
```

Just wanted to see this line get printed when I do a `mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(...)` in a sensor testing application.

Then, I built the module using `mm -B` and then used adb to sync the files to the phone:

```
adb root
adb remount      (need write privileges)
adb sync system
```

The sync seems to complete successfully. The phone restarts about halfway through, but has no problems - my test application works and I see the statement printed in LogCat. However, upon a subsequent reboot, I get a black screen after the Samsung logo appears and CM never boots. To get it responsive again, I have to reflash CM 10.2.

So I'm wondering if I had done something wrong? I only made a small change to the OS and I have read that I can use `adb sync system` to test my changes rather than building CM again which takes substantially longer.

Comment: i am seeing this same behavior not sure what is going on.

Comment: Unfortunately, even years later this seems to be a common failure mode.